# How do I change the position of social login button on Martfury Theme

Tags: magento2, position, ui, social-buttons, change

I'm using Martfury theme.
Now I want to change the social login button position to below the create an account button.
How do I do it?

[image: My Website Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the view file in this path

> public_html/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-social-login/view/frontend/layout

Inside

> customer_account_login.xml

I changed the code to `before="customer.login.container"` to `after="customer.login.container"`

This worked for me.

```
 <block class="Mageplaza\SocialLogin\Block\Popup\Social" after="customer.login.container" ifconfig="sociallogin/general/enabled" name="social-login-popup-authentication-social-login" template="Mageplaza_SocialLogin::form/social.phtml">
```